# Unable to resize image on word document

Tags: java, image, encoding

We are getting image as a byte array and encode it into base64 string then writing this string into word doc but unable to change it's size.

PFB code:

worddocfile // stringbuilder

```
String encodedImage = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(fileType.getFileContent()), "UTF-8");

encodedImage = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";

worddocfile.append("<img style='display:block; width:600px;height:600px;' id='base64image'")
.append(" src='data:image/jpeg;base64,")
.append(encodedImage)
.append("' /> ");
```

Can anyone suggest the solution because it's working on html page but not on word document.

We have already used background image tag but it's not working.

```
<p style="background-image:url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=='); border: 1px solid black;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: contain;width:600px;height:597px;\>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert byte array into an image and place this image inside the WEB-INF folder.
2. Now re scale the converted image with the updated size and store it inside WEB-INF folder.
3. Now convert the re scaled image into byte array and write the bytes on the word doc.

PFB the code:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bis1 = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileType.getFileContent() );

Iterator<?> readers = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("jpg");
//ImageIO is a class containing static methods for locating ImageReaders
//and ImageWriters, and performing simple encoding and decoding. 
ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) readers.next();
Object source1 = bis1; 
ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(source1); 
reader.setInput(iis, true);
ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();
try{
    Image image1 = reader.read(0, param);
    //got an image file image1 -- image1.getWidth(null)
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(650,950, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    //bufferedImage is the RenderedImage to be written
    Graphics2D g2 = bufferedImage.createGraphics();

    g2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    g2.clearRect(0, 0, 650,950);
    g2.drawImage(image1, 0,0,650,950, null);//
    g2.dispose();  
    //mgpath can be WEB-INF folder 
    File imageFile = new File(imgpath+"UpdatedImg.jpg");
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", imageFile);

    FileInputStream fisn = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
    //create FileInputStream which obtains input bytes from a file in a file system
    //FileInputStream is meant for reading streams of raw bytes such as image data. For reading streams of characters, consider using FileReader.

    ByteArrayOutputStream bosn = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] bufn = new byte[1024];
    try {
        for (int readNum1; (readNum1 = fisn.read(bufn)) != -1;) {
            //Writes to this byte array output stream
            bosn.write(bufn, 0, readNum1); 
            System.out.println("read " + readNum1 + " bytes,");
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }

    byte[] outArray1 = bosn.toByteArray();


    String encodedImage = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(outArray1), "UTF-8");
    logger.debug("encodedImage" + encodedImage);

    /// workbookDetails.append("<img src='data:image/png;base64," + encodedImage + "'/>");
    workbookDetails.append("<img style='display:block; width:595px;height:609px;' id='base64image'")
                         .append(" src='data:image/jpeg;base64,")
                         .append(encodedImage)
                         .append("' /> ")
                         .append("                </p>")
                         .append("            </td>")
                         .append("        </tr>")
                         .append("    </tbody>")
                         .append("</table>");
                         .append("</table>");
```

Comment: are both posts part of the same answer? If so you need to [edit] it into this answer and delete the other.